# How do I add a loop to a username and password login (Python)?

Tags: python, authentication

I'm a beginner to programming. I am trying to make a program which will ask the user to create an account and then login with their details which they have just entered...
Here is what I was starting with and now I'm kinda stuck because I also have a syntax error on line 16:

```
from time import sleep

print ("Hey there! To enter the system you are required to sign in")
sleep(2.0)

while True:
    choose=input("If you have an account please type 'SIGN IN', if you do not have an account please type 'CREATE'. ")
    if choose=="SIGN IN":
        print ("You have chosen to sign into your account")
        break
    elif choose=="CREATE":
        print ("You have chosen to create an account")
        break
    username=input("Please enter a username: ")
    password=input("Please enter a memorable password: ")
    else:
        print ("Please enter a valid option, 'SIGN IN' or 'CREATE'")
        sleep(1.0)
```

So any help appreciated, I know im kinda dumb, ive only just started.

Comment: You can't have `username=input("Please enter a username: ")` and such unindented before the `else`. Are you intending those two `input` lines to be inside of the `elif` above that? It looks like those should come after the `else`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i wanted the user to enter their new details after they said they wanted to create an account EG, 
YEs i want to make an account
Program asks:
Now please enter a new username and password.

Then later that user can login with the same details they made...

Comment: Then the `username` and `password` `input` lines should be inside of the `elif choose=="CREATE":` block, before the `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from time import sleep

print ("Hey there! To enter the system you are required to sign in")
sleep(2.0)

while True:
    choose=input("If you have an account please type 'SIGN IN', if you do not have an account please type 'CREATE'. ")
    if choose=="SIGN IN":
        print ("You have chosen to sign into your account")
        break
    elif choose=="CREATE":
        print ("You have chosen to create an account")
        username=input("Please enter a username: ")
        password=input("Please enter a memorable password: ")
        break
    else:
        print ("Please enter a valid option, 'SIGN IN' or 'CREATE'")
        sleep(1.0)
while True:
    input_username = input("Please input a valid username:")
    input_password = input("Please input a valid password:")
    if input_username == username and input_password == password:
        print("Successful login!")
        break
    else:
        print("Either the username or the password is incorrect,please try again")
```

So this is what you wanted to have
It has two while loops
The first one is for choosing between the two options, the second one will process the login credentials if wrong, will repeat the login check for infinity.

P.S: If there is no username or password variable it will throw an error

Comment: I get what you mean, thanks so much for your help! The only issue is now, is that after they user has logged in it is looping the whole process again. I need to add a break to end the first loop expect you can't do that in programming.

Comment: Actually no, to switch over to the second loop I added break statements, which means the first loop will not be repeated.

Comment: The else statement for invalid statement is the only one that will repeat unless you break the loop.

Comment: Ive fixed it now! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the syntax error on line 16 by removing the 'break' statement and indenting the following two lines.

```
from time import sleep

print ("Hey there! To enter the system you are required to sign in")
sleep(2.0)

while True:
    choose=input("If you have an account please type 'SIGN IN', if you do not have an account please type 'CREATE'. ")
    if choose =="SIGN IN":
        print("You have chosen to sign into your account")
    if choose=="CREATE":
        print ("You have chosen to create an account")
        username=input("Please enter a username: ")
        password=input("Please enter a memorable password: ")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option, 'SIGN IN' or 'CREATE'")
        sleep(1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so thanks to @minorwannabedev I've managed to work it out.
Here is my new code:

```
from time import sleep
login = False
username = False
password = False
print ("Hey there! To enter the system you are required to sign in")
sleep(2.0)

while True:
    if login == True:
        break
    choose=input("If you have an account please type 'SIGN-IN', if you do not have an account please type 'CREATE':\n")
    if choose=="CREATE":
        print ("You have chosen to create an account")
        username=input("Please create a username:\n")
        password=input("Please enter a memorable password:\n")
    
    elif choose =="SIGN-IN":
        print("You have chosen to sign into your account")
        while True:
            input_username = input("Please input a valid username:")
            input_password = input("Please input a valid password:")
            if input_username == username and input_password == password:
                print("Successful login")
                login = True
                break

            else:
                print("Either the username or the password is incorrect,please try again")
                break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option, 'SIGN IN' or 'CREATE'")
        sleep(1.0)
```

This took me a little while to work out but it now works!